# Helm: overloading global variables on {{ include }} call?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a shared metadata block, based on the commons library that I would like to override a name for one specific instance. Is it possible?

```yaml
metadata:
  {{ include "common.metadata" (merge (dict ".Values.fullnameSuffix" "-redirect") .) }} # Doesn't work - How do I add a `-redirect` suffix?
  name: {{ include "common.fullname" . }}-redirect # Causes two `name:` attributes
```

Within `common.metadata` there is a call to "fullname" as well:

```yaml
{{ define "common.metadata" -}}
  name: {{ template "common.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- end -}}
```

Is there a way to pass-down a variable override from the first include so that I can override the `name:`? It's specific only to this chart.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) to add a new key/value pair to a dictionary and pass it to slightly modified `common.metadata` helper function.

**values.yaml**

```yaml
fullnameSuffix: redirect
```

**_helpers.tpl**

```golang
{{- define "common.metadata" -}}
  {{- if .suffix }}
  name: {{ template "common.fullname" . }}-{{ .suffix }}
  {{- else }}
  name: {{ template "common.fullname" . }}
  {{- end }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
{{- end -}}
```

**manifest.yaml**

```golang
metadata:
{{- include "common.metadata" (set . "suffix" .Values.fullnameSuffix ) }}
```

If your `fullnameSuffix` is empty, `name` without suffix will be used.